# Return type of Angular 2 life-cycle hook

Tags: angular

It's good practice to define type that function return, like functionName():string instead of functionName(). But what about Angular life-cycle event hooks that is also function after all? Should it be something like ngOninit(): void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifecycle hooks do in fact return `void` according to the documentation for methods such as [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit).

> interface OnInit {    ngOnInit(): void }

It would be best practice to match each return type to that of the documentation. Most should be `void`.

Here are a few:

[OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

[OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

[OnDestroy](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy)

[DoCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck)

Hopefully that helps!